# .htaccess and Rewriterules, change some URLs

Tags: mod-rewrite

I don't know if this is possible, I want my website's URLs to look like :

```
site.com/browse/2-title/page/2
```

while they actually are :

```
site.com/index.php?action=browse&id=2&title=title&page=2
```

Do you have any idea how to do that in rewriterules? is that even possible?

Thank you I'd really appreciate some help here guys :)

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([^/]+)/([^/]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
RewriteRule .* http://site.com/index.php?action=%1&id=%2&title=%3&%4=%5 [L]
```

It will map silently a URL like this one:

`site.com/browse/2-title/page/2`

To:

`http://site.com/index.php?action=browse&id=2&title=title&page=2`

Where `browse`, `2`, `title`, `page` and `2` in the incoming URL are variables passed to the mapped resource.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try that :) and give you an answer